# Do not understand how to insert node into Nth position

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, nodes

> Fill in for the given missing months profits and then print a total list with the missing months added, in their corresponding position, while calculating the sum and average of all the months values

I want to be able to use the `Insert_Nth()` function to move `May` to after `March`. Instead, it is printing after `January`, which obviously is not correct, but I don't know how to do that, or understand how to, either.

I am guessing that I should use an `if` statement, and maybe a `for` loop, to precisely locate the position in the linked list and insert it, but I don't know how to do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip> //library needed for setprecision 

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int value = 0;
    string month;
    node* next;
};

struct NewValues {
    long int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, may = 0;
} n;

void front(node* *head)
{
    node* Dec = new node();
    node* Nov = new node();
    node* Oct = new node();
    
    Dec->value = n.c;
    Dec->month = "December 2021: $";
    Dec->next = *head;
    *head = Dec;

    Nov->value = n.b;
    Nov->month = "November 2021: $";
    Nov->next = Dec;
    *head = Nov;

    Oct->value = n.a;
    Oct->month = "October 2021: $";
    Oct->next = Nov;
    *head = Oct;
}

void end(node* *head)
{
    node* June = new node();
    node* July = new node();        
    node* Aug = new node();
        
        //find the last node
            node* last = *head;
                while (last->next != NULL) {
                    last = last->next;
                }

    Aug->value = n.f;
    Aug->month = "August 2022: $";
    Aug->next = NULL;
    last->next = Aug;
    
    July->value = n.e;
    July->month = "July 2022: $";
    July->next = Aug;
    last->next = July;
    
    June->value = n.d;
    June->month = "June 2022: $";
    June->next = July;
    last->next = June;
}

void Insert_Nth(node* previous)
{
    //1: check if previous node is null
        if(previous == NULL) {
        cout << "\nPrevious cannot be null" << endl;
        return;
        }
    
    //2: prepare a newnode assign value
    node* May = new node();
    May->month = "May 2022: $";
    May->value = n.may;
    
    //3: insert newnode after previous
    May->next = previous->next;
    previous->next = May;
}

void sumOfNodes(node* head, long double* sum)
{
    // if head = NULL
    if (!head)
        return;

    // recursively traverse the remaining nodes
    sumOfNodes(head->next, sum);

    // accumulate sum
    *sum = *sum + head->value;
}

int sumOfNodesUtil(node* head)
{
    long double sum = 0;

    // find the sum of  nodes
    sumOfNodes(head, &sum);

    // required sum
    return sum;
}

void printList(node* n)
{
    cout << "\nList of earnings from October 2021 - August 2022\n" << endl;
    
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->month << n->value << endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(node* *head_ref)
{
    /* deref head_ref to get the real head */
    node* current = *head_ref;
    node* next = NULL;
  
        while (current != NULL) {
            next = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = next;
        }
  
    /* deref head_ref to affect the real head back
        in the caller. */
    *head_ref = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, This program takes in input for unaccounted months from your";
    cout << " salary over the months and prints them out, \nalong with the total and average." << endl;
    cout << "\nThere are a total There are 11 months and 7 months unaccounted for..." << endl;
    cout << "please enter in the data for the missing months when prompted" << endl;
    
    cout << "\n------------------------" << endl;
    
    cout << "October 2021: $";
    cin >> n.a;

    cout << "November 2021: $";
    cin >> n.b;

    cout << "December 2021: $";
    cin >> n.c;

    cout << "May 2022: $";
    cin >> n.may;
    
    cout << "June 2022: $";
    cin >> n.d;

    cout << "July 2022: $";
    cin >> n.e;

    cout << "August 2022: $";
    cin >> n.f;
    
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    
    node* head = new node();
    node* second = new node();
    node* third = new node();
    node* fourth = new node();

    head->value = 500;
    head->month = "January 2022: $";
    head->next = second;

    second->value = 125;
    second->month = "Febuary 2022: $";
    second->next = third;

    third->value = 200;
    third->month = "March 2022: $";
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->value = 300;
    fourth->month = "April 2022: $";
    fourth->next = NULL;

    Insert_Nth(head);
    front(&head);
    end(&head);
    printList(head);
    
    long double avg = sumOfNodesUtil(head) / 11;

    cout << "\n\n------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Total earnings: $" << setprecision(6) << sumOfNodesUtil(head) << endl;
    cout << "Average: $" << setprecision(6) << avg << endl;
    
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\nDeleting Linked List..." << endl;
    
    deleteList(&head);
    
    cout << "\nLinked List Deleted\n\n\tProgram Terminated..." << endl;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Make sure there is a Nth position...

Comment: @HW19 "I want to be able to use the Insert_Nth() function to move May to after March"  Till now I have thought that May follows April.:)

Comment: How will you insert at the 0th position? Why did you swaithc from `node**` to `node*` for that function? Also why do you suddenly use `head_ref` in `deleteList` when you called it just `head` before.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this code, what did you see? This is what a debugger is for and if you don't know how to use it, this is a good opportunity to learn running your program one line at a time in a debugger, monitoring all variables and their values as they change and analysing your program's logic and execution. It should be possible for you to use your debugger to find all simple problems in this and all future programs you write, all by yourself.

Comment: @HW19 The function Insert_Nth has neither N.:)

Comment: You should learn about construtors and member initialization.

Comment: @HW19 This code snippet         if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = June;
            return;
        } produces memory leaks.

Comment: Leaves June unitinialized which is the real problem.

Comment: It should be `node* *last;` in `end()` to fit with the function declaration. Or just keep using head.

Comment: The current behaviour of `insert_Nth`  is to ensure the caller has supplied an a node at `previous` that can be attached to. Then it makes node `May`. Then it places `May` before `previous`. Then it places `previous` before `May` making a loop. One thing I find helpful when working with linked lists is to draw picture of what you need to do and then follow your code exactly and try to draw the same picture. If you cannot, you should be able to see where the drawings diverge immediately and you may have a good idea of what you needed to do instead.

Comment: cout << "Hello, This program is not minimal because it takes input and spits out a lot of instructions. To make it easier on the people helping you, hardcode values and strip out unnecessary I/O. Also, end the program as soon as you can -- after calling `Insert_Nth`, print the list and end. Remove now-unused functions. Leave just enough to reproduce the problem, c.f. [mre]."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Fixed Code***

previously I had forgotten to set a value for the `previous`, so it wasnt given a specified place to insert in the linked list, but it has one now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iomanip> //library needed for setprecision 

using namespace std;

class node {
public:
    int value = 0;
    string month;
    node* next;
};

struct NewValues {
    long int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, may = 0;
} n;

void front(node* *head)
{
    node* Dec = new node();
    node* Nov = new node();
    node* Oct = new node();
    
    Dec->value = n.c;
    Dec->month = "December 2021: $";
    Dec->next = *head;
    *head = Dec;

    Nov->value = n.b;
    Nov->month = "November 2021: $";
    Nov->next = Dec;
    *head = Nov;

    Oct->value = n.a;
    Oct->month = "October 2021: $";
    Oct->next = Nov;
    *head = Oct;
}

void end(node* *head)
{
    node* June = new node();
    node* July = new node();        
    node* Aug = new node();

    //if linked list is empty, newnode will be a head node
        if (*head == NULL) {
            *head = June;
            return;
        }
        
        //find the last node
            node* last = *head;
                while (last->next != NULL) {
                    last = last->next;
                }

    Aug->value = n.f;
    Aug->month = "August 2022: $";
    Aug->next = NULL;
    last->next = Aug;
    
    July->value = n.e;
    July->month = "July 2022: $";
    July->next = Aug;
    last->next = July;
    
    June->value = n.d;
    June->month = "June 2022: $";
    June->next = July;
    last->next = June;
}

void Insert_Nth(node* previous, node* *fourth)
{
    //1: check if previous node is null
        if(previous == NULL) {
        cout << "\nPrevious cannot be null" << endl;
        return;
        }
    
    //2: prepare a newnode assign value
    node* May = new node();
    May->month = "May 2022: $";
    May->value = n.may;
    
    previous = *fourth;
    
    //3: insert newnode after previous
    May->next = previous->next;
    previous->next = May;
}

void sumOfNodes(node* head, long double* sum)
{
    // if head = NULL
    if (!head)
        return;

    // recursively traverse the remaining nodes
    sumOfNodes(head->next, sum);

    // accumulate sum
    *sum = *sum + head->value;
}

int sumOfNodesUtil(node* head)
{
    long double sum = 0;

    // find the sum of  nodes
    sumOfNodes(head, &sum);

    // required sum
    return sum;
}

void printList(node* n)
{
    cout << "\nList of earnings from October 2021 - August 2022\n" << endl;
    
    while (n != NULL) {
        cout << n->month << n->value << endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(node* *head_ref)
{
    /* deref head_ref to get the real head */
    node* current = *head_ref;
    node* next = NULL;
  
        while (current != NULL) {
            next = current->next;
            free(current);
            current = next;
        }
  
    /* deref head_ref to affect the real head back
        in the caller. */
    *head_ref = NULL;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, This program takes in input for unaccounted months from your";
    cout << " salary over the months and prints them out, \nalong with the total and average." << endl;
    cout << "\nThere are a total There are 11 months and 7 months unaccounted for..." << endl;
    cout << "please enter in the data for the missing months when prompted" << endl;
    
    cout << "\n------------------------" << endl;
    
    cout << "October 2021: $";
    cin >> n.a;

    cout << "November 2021: $";
    cin >> n.b;

    cout << "December 2021: $";
    cin >> n.c;

    cout << "May 2022: $";
    cin >> n.may;
    
    cout << "June 2022: $";
    cin >> n.d;

    cout << "July 2022: $";
    cin >> n.e;

    cout << "August 2022: $";
    cin >> n.f;
    
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;
    
    node* head = new node();
    node* second = new node();
    node* third = new node();
    node* fourth = new node();

    head->value = 500;
    head->month = "January 2022: $";
    head->next = second;

    second->value = 125;
    second->month = "Febuary 2022: $";
    second->next = third;

    third->value = 200;
    third->month = "March 2022: $";
    third->next = fourth;

    fourth->value = 300;
    fourth->month = "April 2022: $";
    fourth->next = NULL;
    
    front(&head);
    end(&head);
    Insert_Nth(head,&fourth);
    printList(head);
    
    long double avg = sumOfNodesUtil(head) / 11;

    cout << "\n\n------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "Total earnings: $" << setprecision(6) << sumOfNodesUtil(head) << endl;
    cout << "Average: $" << setprecision(6) << avg << endl;
    
    cout << "------------------------" << endl;

    cout << "\nDeleting Linked List..." << endl;
    
    deleteList(&head);
    
    cout << "\nLinked List Deleted\n\n\tProgram Terminated..." << endl;
}
```